# How to install and configure Kara Web Framework?

Tags: kotlin

I want to get started with web development, but I am having trouble installing Kara on my computer. The web site states that the Github repository includes a bash script for Mac OS-X, but I cannot find the script anywhere, just .iml files and the source code. There is very little information on the web site about how to configure Kara on my machine. Any pointers or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The repository [README.md](https://github.com/TinyMission/kara/blob/master/README.md) says: "Check out karaframework.com to get a quick overview of the project. (**Caution:** Some contents are outdated.)". I don't think there is a `kara` script anymore. Downloading from the Build Server is also unavailable. Maybe the project is dead (?) and you should consider alternatives.

Comment: From https://github.com/TinyMission/kara :

> Download the repository, load the project in IntelliJ IDEA (can take a while), then choose the "Sample Server" configuration in the toolbar and run it.

Comment: Kara is not dead, but it's really not in a state where it can be used by someone getting started with Web development. Please consider using a more mature framework, such as Spring Boot.